# replace a directive with a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am a newbie and have been learning through sample codes. I came across this directive that checks for allowed Access level.I need to replace it with a function that i could call like:

```
router.get('/', functioname(user.role), musicians.findAll);
```

i.e allow this path to be accessed only if this function returns true else false.

I need not update any CSS but needs the path to be restricted as per info returned by the function.

How do I get access level and role here?

However, I have this directive which I need to replace with a function which I could use likewise.

```
     angular.module('angular-client-side-auth')
    .directive('accessLevel', ['Auth', function(Auth) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                var prevDisp = element.css('display')
                    , userRole
                    , accessLevel;

                $scope.user = Auth.user;
                $scope.$watch('user', function(user) {
                    if(user.role)
                        userRole = user.role;
                    updateCSS();
                }, true);

                attrs.$observe('accessLevel', function(al) {
                    if(al) accessLevel = $scope.$eval(al);
                    updateCSS();
                });

                function updateCSS() {
                    if(userRole && accessLevel) {
                        if(!Auth.authorize(accessLevel, userRole))
                            element.css('display', 'none');
                        else
                            element.css('display', prevDisp);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }])
```

It is using this service:

```
angular.module('angular-client-side-auth')
.factory('Auth', function($http, $cookieStore){

    var accessLevels = routingConfig.accessLevels
        , userRoles = routingConfig.userRoles
        , currentUser = $cookieStore.get('user') || { username: '', role: userRoles.public };

    $cookieStore.remove('user');

    function changeUser(user) {
        angular.extend(currentUser, user);
    }

    return {
        authorize: function(accessLevel, role) {
            if(role === undefined) {
                role = currentUser.role;
            }

            return accessLevel.bitMask & role.bitMask;
        } }
```

Can I please get some help with this?

Comment: you already have the function, `Auth.authorize()` in your factory that you can call.

Comment: But how do I get access level and role there?

Comment: err, what do you mean? the function takes an access level, and an optional role, and returns a bitmask.  wherever you call this from, you must already have a user object you want to check....